# Moving overlapping sliding vertical images when scrolling

Tags: css, image, scroll, slide

Basically, I'd like to understand how the effect with the vertically scrolling, but overlapping images on the amazing [Beolit 15](http://www.beoplay.com/products/beolit15#materials) works.

What I found out so far is that they use a container `div` which again contains four `div`s that are positioned absolutely to the upper left corner of the container. So far, so good. Apart from that, the four `div`s all have the same size, feature a background-image that is sized as `cover`, and have different `z-index` values to make sure that they are in the correct order on top of each other.

Then, what they added is a `clip` style that always starts in the upper left corner of each of the four `div`s, always has the same width, but they differ in their vertical length. The top-most is the shortest one, the second-top-most is the second-shortest one, and so on…

So far, I already have two questions:

- How do they get the `673px` width? Isn't this depending on screen resolution? Why is it exactly this value?
- How did they get the height of teach of the clipping rectangles? Why exactly those values? (Of course, because otherwise it wouldn't work, but how did they get those values? I'm sure not by trial and error…)

Now, apart from that, you can see that when you scroll, basically all they do is update the lower border of the clipping rectangle. This way it looks as if they were sliding up, and move above the images, while they stay fixed.

What I do not get here is how they do this. Obviously they have *somehow* attached to the `window.scroll` event, but how exactly?

Comment: The height is set to the client viewport height on load, and the width is based on the width of the `.images` div on load. The scroll and the rest is done through a js script they've inlined. I'm unsure why they developed it this way rather than having absolute divs for each section and using `background-attachment: fixed;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They add a `.fixed` class to `div.images` via `e.startEngine()` once it reaches the top edge of the viewport and remove it via `e.stopEngine()` when you scrolled through all images. This triggers the following styles:

```
.focus .images.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: calc(50% - 30px);
}
```

`calc(50% - 30px)` is probably the `673px` you are searching for.

The style every image gets looks like:

```
height: 928px;
clip: rect(0px 597px 1856px 0px);
```

which can be expanded to:

```
height: [window.innerHeight];
clip: rect(
    0px
    [window.innerWidth / 2 - 30]
    [
        this.parentNode.parentNode.offsetTop +
        document.querySelector('.inpagenav').offsetHeight +
        (window.innerHeight * IMAGENUMBER) - 
        window.scrollY
    ]
    0px
);
```

The scroll event is attached via `e.Tools.bindEvent(window, "scroll", w)` and the function `w` calls `e.Tools.clipY()` which sets the `clip` styles for each image.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer :-). But I have a few questions on this: What do you mean by `e.startEngine()` and `e.stopEngine()`? And: What is `e.Tools`?

Comment: `e` refers to a custom object `window.Focus` and `e.Tools` refers to `window.Focus.Tools`. The `Focus` object (i.e. `e`) looks like it’s used as a namespace to store functions in it. You can view the source code of the page and search for `window.Focus` or `e.startEngine` to see the related code parts.